# MongoDB: Why is model.find() returning 'model.find is not a function' in some instances, but not in others

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, find

I'm currently working on a project that involves storing session data using MongoDB. I've defined a SessionModel in Mongoose to represent session documents in the database, and I'm using a sessionHandler.js file to export four functions to store, load, delete, and update session data. While the other functions in the sessionHandler.js file are working fine, I'm facing an issue with the storeArticleData() function. When I try to use the SessionModel.find() function inside storeArticleData() to retrieve all session documents from the database, it throws a "SessionModel.find is not a function" error. I'm wondering why this is happening and how I can fix it.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const sessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  shop: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  articleData: { type: Object, required: true },
});

const SessionModel = mongoose.model("session", sessionSchema);

export default SessionModel;
```

I am also using a sessionHandler.js file that exports four functions to store, load, delete, and update session data. Here's a simplified version of that code:

```
import { Session } from "@shopify/shopify-api";
import SessionModel from "./models/SessionModel.js";
import CryptoJS from "crypto-js";

const storeSession = async (session) => {
   await SessionModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { id: session.id },
    {
      content: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
        JSON.stringify(session),
        process.env.ENCRYPTION_STRING
      ).toString(),
      shop: session.shop,
      articleData: {},
    },

    { upsert: true }
  );

  return true;
};

const storeArticleData = async (shopName, data) => {
  const doc = await SessionModel.find();
  // The line above is not working, throwing a "SessionModel.find is not a function" error.
  // await SessionModel.findOneByIdAndUpdate(
  //   { id: "offline_" + shopName },
  //   {
  //     articleData: data,
  //   }
  // );
  return true;
};

const loadSession = async (id) => {
  // ...
};

const deleteSession = async (id) => {
  // ...
};

const sessionHandler = {
  storeSession,
  loadSession,
  deleteSession,
  storeArticleData,
};

export default sessionHandler;
```

As a simple example I am trying to use the SessionModel.find() function inside storeArticleData() to retrieve all session documents from the database, but it throws a "SessionModel.find is not a function" error. However, when I use the SessionModel.functions in the other areas (for example in storeSession() it works fine.

Why is SessionModel.find() not working for storeArticleData(), but working for the other instances where SessionModel is used in the same file? Am I missing something here? Any help would be appreciated.

Sorry if this doesn't make complete sense, I'm new to MongoDB (and databases in general).